# fake android account for testing

Tags: android, android-emulator

I would like to have a fake android account I can use for testing adding/deleting/merging/referencing contacts.  In my searches, I'm a little surprised something hasn't turned up.  I am new to the android scene.  How do people normally go about this?

Thank you.

Comment: Hark!  Looks like I read wrong.  I CAN add contacts without first creating an account on the emulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the android emulator that comes with the SDK, that is about it unless you are willing to use your own device.

I'm not sure if the android emulator allows access to contacts though.

Comment: I have been using the emulator, but when it comes time to view the contacts, it says that I need an account on the emulator.  I am unsure how to create a fake account on the emulator which I could then add contacts to...

Answer (score -1):

For testing, you can just create another gmail.com account (e.g., mytestaccount@gmail.com) and use that to sign in on the emulator (or test device, if you have one). Remember to sign out of your current Google/gmail.com account so you get the "Sign up" option on the Gmail page.